# python: Interplay between lib/site-packages/site.py and lib/site.py

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, sys.path

Due to a specific [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25710724/prevent-python-from-loading-a-pth-file) which I managed to solve, I spent most of today figuring out how site.py(s) work. There is a point which I don't understand.

As far as I understand, when python is loaded, first `lib/python2.7/site-packages/site.py` is run. It goes over `PYTHONPATH`, searches for `lib/python2.7/site.py`, and imports it. This file has the `addsitedir` method, that not only adds a path to `sys.path`, but also processes `*.pth` files which exists on it. At this point, `main()` from `lib/python2.7/site.py` is ran, and `addsitedir` is ran on site-packages and on user-site-packages.

Now comes the weird part. Now we go back to `lib/python2.7/site-packages/site.py`, which goes over each path in pythonpath, and runs `addsitedir` on it. I find this weird for two reasons:

1. `addsitedir` is ran on `lib/python2.7/site-packages` twice.
2. This is not so bad in itself (nothing can be added to sys.path twice), but it seems that `lib/python2.7/site.py` has a mechanism for allowing the ambitious user to manipulate `sys.path` by implementing a `usercustomize` module (hey, it's even in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/site.html)). Obviously, when you implement such a mechanism, you want to make sure the user gets in last, so he can have control over everything added to `sys.path`. But this is not the case here (as I was frustrated to find out). Most likely, the second call to `lib/python2.7/site-packages` will override everything done in `usercustomize`.

I know it's terrible, but I added a print statement to `addsitedir`, printing the path it receives,  so I could show what's going on. These are the paths processed:

```
/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages #lib/python2.7/site.py
/home/user/py/lib/python2.7/site-packages     #lib/python2.7/site.py
#This is where your usercustomize runs
#Followin calls are from lib/python2.7/site-packages/site.py
/home/user/py/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy-1.9.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg
/home/user/Develop/Python/myproject
/home/user/lmfit-0.7.2
/home/user/py/lib/python2.7/site-packages #NOTE: this runs a second time
```

So what am I asking here? :)

A. I'd appreciate insights as to why the second call to site-packages is needed.

B. Is `usercustomize` indeed limited as I believe it is due to this implementation? Considering this, how would you implement something *removing* paths from sys.path (theoretically)?

---

Requested debug output:

```
:genie39:~ ;-) python2.7 -v
# installing zipimport hook
import zipimport # builtin
# installed zipimport hook
# /home/user/py/lib/python2.7/site-packages/site.pyc matches /home/user/py/lib/python2.7/site-packages/site.py
import site # precompiled from /home/user/py/lib/python2.7/site-packages/site.pyc
# /home/user/py/lib/python2.7/os.pyc matches /home/user/py/lib/python2.7/os.py
import os # precompiled from /home/user/py/lib/python2.7/os.pyc
import errno # builtin
import posix # builtin
# /home/user/py/lib/python2.7/posixpath.pyc matches /home/user/py/lib/python2.7/posixpath.py
import posixpath # precompiled from /home/user/py/lib/python2.7/posixpath.pyc
# /home/user/py/lib/python2.7/stat.pyc matches /home/user/py/lib/python2.7/stat.py
import stat # precompiled from /home/user/py/lib/python2.7/stat.pyc
# /home/user/py/lib/python2.7/genericpath.pyc matches /home/user/py/lib/python2.7/genericpath.py
import genericpath # precompiled from /home/user/py/lib/python2.7/genericpath.pyc
# /home/user/py/lib/python2.7/warnings.pyc matches /home/user/py/lib/python2.7/warnings.py
import warnings # precompiled from /home/user/py/lib/python2.7/warnings.pyc
# /home/user/py/lib/python2.7/linecache.pyc matches /home/user/py/lib/python2.7/linecache.py
import linecache # precompiled from /home/user/py/lib/python2.7/linecache.pyc
# /home/user/py/lib/python2.7/types.pyc matches /home/user/py/lib/python2.7/types.py
import types # precompiled from /home/user/py/lib/python2.7/types.pyc
# /home/user/py/lib/python2.7/UserDict.pyc matches /home/user/py/lib/python2.7/UserDict.py
import UserDict # precompiled from /home/user/py/lib/python2.7/UserDict.pyc
# /home/user/py/lib/python2.7/_abcoll.pyc matches /home/user/py/lib/python2.7/_abcoll.py
import _abcoll # precompiled from /home/user/py/lib/python2.7/_abcoll.pyc
# /home/user/py/lib/python2.7/abc.pyc matches /home/user/py/lib/python2.7/abc.py
import abc # precompiled from /home/user/py/lib/python2.7/abc.pyc
# /home/user/py/lib/python2.7/_weakrefset.pyc matches /home/user/py/lib/python2.7/_weakrefset.py
import _weakrefset # precompiled from /home/user/py/lib/python2.7/_weakrefset.pyc
import _weakref # builtin
# /home/user/py/lib/python2.7/copy_reg.pyc matches /home/user/py/lib/python2.7/copy_reg.py
import copy_reg # precompiled from /home/user/py/lib/python2.7/copy_reg.pyc
import imp # builtin
# /home/user/py/lib/python2.7/site.pyc matches /home/user/py/lib/python2.7/site.py
import site # precompiled from /home/user/py/lib/python2.7/site.pyc
# /home/user/py/lib/python2.7/traceback.pyc matches /home/user/py/lib/python2.7/traceback.py
import traceback # precompiled from /home/user/py/lib/python2.7/traceback.pyc
# /home/user/py/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.pyc matches /home/user/py/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.py
import sysconfig # precompiled from /home/user/py/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.pyc
# /home/user/py/lib/python2.7/re.pyc matches /home/user/py/lib/python2.7/re.py
import re # precompiled from /home/user/py/lib/python2.7/re.pyc
# /home/user/py/lib/python2.7/sre_compile.pyc matches /home/user/py/lib/python2.7/sre_compile.py
import sre_compile # precompiled from /home/user/py/lib/python2.7/sre_compile.pyc
import _sre # builtin
# /home/user/py/lib/python2.7/sre_parse.pyc matches /home/user/py/lib/python2.7/sre_parse.py
import sre_parse # precompiled from /home/user/py/lib/python2.7/sre_parse.pyc
# /home/user/py/lib/python2.7/sre_constants.pyc matches /home/user/py/lib/python2.7/sre_constants.py
import sre_constants # precompiled from /home/user/py/lib/python2.7/sre_constants.pyc
# /home/user/py/lib/python2.7/_sysconfigdata.pyc matches /home/user/py/lib/python2.7/_sysconfigdata.py
import _sysconfigdata # precompiled from /home/user/py/lib/python2.7/_sysconfigdata.pyc
# zipimport: found 604 names in /home/user/py/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pytz-2014.7-py2.7.egg
# zipimport: found 20 names in /home/user/py/lib/python2.7/site-packages/hashlib-20081119-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg
# zipimport: found 40 names in /home/user/py/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pysqlite-2.6.3-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg
# zipimport: found 7 names in /home/user/py/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mock-1.0.1-py2.7.egg
import encodings # directory /home/user/py/lib/python2.7/encodings
# /home/user/py/lib/python2.7/encodings/__init__.pyc matches /home/user/py/lib/python2.7/encodings/__init__.py
import encodings # precompiled from /home/user/py/lib/python2.7/encodings/__init__.pyc
# /home/user/py/lib/python2.7/codecs.pyc matches /home/user/py/lib/python2.7/codecs.py
import codecs # precompiled from /home/user/py/lib/python2.7/codecs.pyc
import _codecs # builtin
# /home/user/py/lib/python2.7/encodings/aliases.pyc matches /home/user/py/lib/python2.7/encodings/aliases.py
import encodings.aliases # precompiled from /home/user/py/lib/python2.7/encodings/aliases.pyc
# /home/user/py/lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.pyc matches /home/user/py/lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.py
import encodings.utf_8 # precompiled from /home/user/py/lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.pyc
Python 2.7.8 (default, Sep  7 2014, 12:14:33) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
dlopen("/home/user/py/lib/python2.7/site-packages/readline-6.2.4.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/readline.so", 2);
import readline # dynamically loaded from /home/user/py/lib/python2.7/site-packages/readline-6.2.4.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/readline.so
>>>
```

Output of `python -vv` is [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/31344261/debug.txt)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `lib/python2.7/site-packages/site.py` file is **not normally loaded**. That's because it is `lib/python2.7/site.py`'s job to add the `site-packages` paths to `sys.path` to begin with, and the `site.py` in `site-packages` is simply not visible. If you have a `site.py` in `site-packages` then that is an error, there should be no such file there.

What happens in an unpatched Python without is:

- Python starts, with a limited `sys.path`. `site-packages` is *not part of this list*, unless you set a `PYTHONPATH` variable that includes it anyway.
- Python imports `site.py`, it'll import the one listed first on `sys.path`.
- `lib/python2.7/site.py` is found and loaded
- `site.py` adds `site-packages` to `sys.path`

That's it, no further `site.py` modules are loaded. Even if you tried, it'd find the module that was *already imported*; `sys.modules['site']` exists and holds objects loaded from `lib/python2.7/site.py`.

Your installation, however, has an older `setuptools` installed, and it includes a [special version of `site.py`](https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/src/b8c395c05a4724ee678191e6f84c443214bde729/site.py?at=setuptools-0.6), which the `easy_install` command [will install into `site-packages`](https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/src/b8c395c05a4724ee678191e6f84c443214bde729/setuptools/command/easy_install.py?at=setuptools#cl-1067) if not yet present. It'll load the original `site.py` by explicitly scanning the original `sys.path` with any `PYTHONPATH`-supplied paths ignored and [loading the original `site.py` module manually](https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/src/b8c395c05a4724ee678191e6f84c443214bde729/site.py?at=setuptools-0.6#cl-25) using the [`imp.find_module()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/imp.html#imp.find_module) and [`imp.load_module()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/imp.html#imp.load_module) low-level functions, thus bypassing the normal module cache.

Its intent was to alter the `sys.path` order to give `PYTHONPATH`-listed `.pth` files a higher precedence, see the [original commit adding the patch](https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/commits/ff4d9e23713fb8f5457964ca0dbe165c1682edc1):

> Note: this version includes a hacked 'site.py' to support processing
>   .pth files in directories that come *before* site-packages on sys.path.

The patch has been removed entirely from more recent `setuptools` releases, [as early as 2006 in the original `setuptools`](https://bitbucket.org/tarek/distribute/issue/321/).

So, either your Linux distribution has been set up to add `lib/python2.7/site-packages` to your `PYTHONPATH` or your shell has this set up for you, or your Python has been patched to include it, **and** you have the old `setuptools` 'patch' in your `site-packages`.

It is entirely safe to remove that file.

Comment: This answer is definitive and extremely helpful. Most likely, `site-packages/site.py` came from installing **setuptools**. The *old way* of installing it to a custom Python installation [required setting PYTHONPATH](http://askbot.org/en/question/2492/how-to-install-python-easy_install-python-distutils-in-root-or-non-root-account/). However, easy_install [no longer requires that](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/easy_install.html#custom-installation-locations). "[A]ll of these [older ways] are effectively deprecated by the User scheme brought in by PEP-370 in Python 2.6."