# Pyinstaller "failed to import the site module"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

I've been trying to use PyInstaller for some time as it can turn a Python script into a single `.exe` file, instead of having a lib file and DLLs like `cx_freeze` does for example. So it's easier for my users to update the program when I push as it's "less" stuff to download.

However, when I run "pyinstaller CLI.py", I get the following error:

```
76 INFO: PyInstaller: 4.3
76 INFO: Python: 3.9.5
87 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.19042-SP0
88 INFO: wrote C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\UnknownAIO\CLI.spec
91 INFO: UPX is not available.
92 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\UnknownAIO',
 'C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\Lib\\site-packages\\site.py',
 'C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\UnknownAIO']
104 INFO: checking Analysis
104 INFO: Building Analysis because Analysis-00.toc is non existent
104 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
108 INFO: Caching module graph hooks...
115 WARNING: Several hooks defined for module 'win32ctypes.core'. Please take care they do not conflict.
119 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
Fatal Python error: init_import_site: Failed to import the site module
Python runtime state: initialized
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\site.py", line 617, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\site.py", line 604, in main
    known_paths = addsitepackages(known_paths)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\site.py", line 387, in addsitepackages
    addsitedir(sitedir, known_paths)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\site.py", line 226, in addsitedir
    addpackage(sitedir, name, known_paths)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\site.py", line 175, in addpackage
    f = io.TextIOWrapper(io.open_code(fullname), encoding="locale")
LookupError: unknown encoding: locale
Fatal Python error: init_import_site: Failed to import the site module
Python runtime state: initialized
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\site.py", line 617, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\site.py", line 604, in main
    known_paths = addsitepackages(known_paths)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\site.py", line 387, in addsitepackages
    addsitedir(sitedir, known_paths)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\site.py", line 226, in addsitedir
    addpackage(sitedir, name, known_paths)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\site.py", line 175, in addpackage
    f = io.TextIOWrapper(io.open_code(fullname), encoding="locale")
LookupError: unknown encoding: locale
2115 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook distutils from 'C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_find_module_path\\hook-distutils.py'.
2116 INFO: distutils: retargeting to non-venv dir 'C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib'
4439 INFO: Caching module dependency graph...
4528 INFO: running Analysis Analysis-00.toc
4542 INFO: Adding Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls to dependent assemblies of final executable
  required by c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe
4604 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-core-path-l1-1-0.dll dependency of c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python39.dll
4614 INFO: Analyzing C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\UnknownAIO\CLI.py
5032 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook site from 'C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_find_module_path\\hook-site.py'.
5033 INFO: site: retargeting to fake-dir 'C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\fake-modules'
8190 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook urllib3.packages.six.moves from 'C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\pre_safe_import_module\\hook-urllib3.packages.six.moves.py'.
Fatal Python error: init_import_site: Failed to import the site module
Python runtime state: initialized
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\site.py", line 617, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\site.py", line 604, in main
    known_paths = addsitepackages(known_paths)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\site.py", line 387, in addsitepackages
    addsitedir(sitedir, known_paths)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\site.py", line 226, in addsitedir
    addpackage(sitedir, name, known_paths)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\site.py", line 175, in addpackage
    f = io.TextIOWrapper(io.open_code(fullname), encoding="locale")
LookupError: unknown encoding: locale
pre-safe-import-module hook failed, needs fixing.
```

Any help would be amazing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something is amiss with your Python installation. The ["site-specific configuration hook" `site.py`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/site.html?module-site) is normally found in the `Lib` folder just underneath the Python install directory. But according to your error log, PyInstaller finds it in `Lib/site-packages`.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26035458) from 2014:

> If you have a `site.py` in `site-packages` then that is an error, there should be no such file there.

It's referring to Python 2.7, but explains well what `site.py` does and still applies to newer Python versions, such as Python 3.9 here.

Furthermore, the code line

```
f = io.TextIOWrapper(io.open_code(fullname), encoding="locale")
```

in your custom `site.py` is wrong. There is no [(standard) encoding](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings) with the name `'locale'`. Which is why it raises that `LookupError`. That [same line of code in the `site.py` included with Python 3.9](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Lib/site.py#L160) does not use the optional `encoding` argument.